# getting a black screen when running a kivy code

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to learn kivy but when i installed it and codded my first class am getting a black screen.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text="Hello World")

MyApp().run()
```

and this showing on IDLE

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\WORK\.kivy\logs\kivy_18-12-03_16.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.1
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.1 (v3.7.1:260ec2c36a, Oct 20 2018, 14:57:15) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Activate GLES2/ANGLE context
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <angle_sdl2>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b"OpenGL ES 2.0 (ANGLE 2.1.0.b'')">
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Google Inc.'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'ANGLE (Intel(R) HD Graphics 3000 Direct3D11 vs_4_1 ps_4_1)'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 2, 0
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b"OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.00 (ANGLE 2.1.0.b'')">
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <8192>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
```

Comment: Try run it from commando line